# Combining results in second table when Joining two tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have these two tables that I can't change, and I am trying to query and combine some data together from both of them. What I would ideally like to do is to combine omit rows where FieldTime2 is 0, when there are more than two results for the same FieldID. If FieldTime2 is 0 and there is only one result, then I want the row displayed.

Could you possibly count the FieldID in Table2 and assign a number if count is greater than 1, or something like that?

Table 1

```
ID  FieldID  FieldTime
------------------------
 1   A        10
 2   B        15
 3   C        20
```

Table 2

```
 ID  FieldID  FieldTime2
------------------------
 1   A        0
 2   A        15
 3   B        0
 4   C        10
```

Desired Output:

```
FieldID  FieldTime  FieldTime2
------------------------------
  A      10         15
  B      15         0
  C      20         10
```

My Output:

```
FieldID  FieldTime  FieldTime2
------------------------------
      A      10         0
      A      10         15
      B      15         0
      C      20         10
```

CODE:

```
SELECT
    m.FieldID, 
    m.FieldTime,
    n.FieldTime2,

from Table1 m
   Join Table2 n
       ON m.FieldID = n.FieldID

Where n.FieldTime > 0
```

Comment: in cases where there are multiple records, is there always 1 with a value and the others are 0, or would there multiples with a value > 0?

Comment: With multiple records only one will be 0.

Comment: Do you want all of the non-0 records to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution that comes to mind is to use a LEFT JOIN query, like this:

```
SELECT
    m.FieldID, 
    m.FieldTime,
    COALESCE(n.FieldTime2, 0) as FieldTime2,

from Table1 m
  left Join Table2 n
       ON m.FieldID = n.FieldID and n.FieldTime2 > 0

Where n.FieldTime > 0
```

if there are multiple non-zero records in the Table2 and only one is desired then the query will be a bit complex:

```
with n as (
select *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FieldID ORDER BY FieldTime2 DESC) rn
from Table2
)
SELECT
    m.FieldID, 
    m.FieldTime,
    COALESCE(n.FieldTime2, 0) as FieldTime2,

from Table1 m
  LEFT Join n
       ON m.FieldID = n.FieldID and n.rn = 1

Where n.FieldTime > 0
```

Comment: This will not be correct for the case where there is only 1 record with a value of 0. As per the OP's request: "If FieldTime2 is 0 and there is only one result, then I want the row displayed."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have provided the first solution before OP's comment. Now, I have the solution for both

Comment: Thanks, I tried both solutions and the first one actually worked. When it is two entries in table 2, with one being 0 and the other a number like 5, the solution only shows 5 and if it is just one entry with a 0, it shows the entry with the 0.

Comment: What about 1 entry and value 0?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your data sample, and the assumption that there will be only 1 `FieldTime` with a `value > 0` you could simply use `MAX()` to resolve your problem:

```
SELECT
    m.FieldID, 
    m.FieldTime,
    MAX(n.FieldTime2),
FROM Table1 m
JOIN Table2 n ON m.FieldID = n.FieldID
WHERE n.FieldTime > 0
GROUP BY m.FieldID, m.FieldTime
```

Of course this solution will not render the correct output if there could be multiple `FieldTime` records that have a `value > 0` in which case you could solve your problem using a `UNION`:

```
--cases with one record:
SELECT
    m.FieldID, 
    m.FieldTime,
    n.FieldTime2
FROM Table1 m
JOIN Table2 n ON m.FieldID = n.FieldID
Where m.FieldID in
(
   SELECT FieldID 
   FROM Table2
   HAVING COUNT(FieldID) = 1 -- only one record exists
)
UNION 
--cases with multiple records
SELECT
    m.FieldID, 
    m.FieldTime,
    n.FieldTime2
FROM Table1 m
JOIN Table2 n ON m.FieldID = n.FieldID
Where m.FieldID not in --make sure we select the rest of the records
(
   SELECT FieldID 
   FROM Table2
   HAVING COUNT(FieldID) = 1 
) AND n.FieldTime2 > 0 -- make sure to exclude the 0 records.
```

Please note that this is not tested, so expect typos, poor performance or mistakes. :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this also. I gave you rep, but it doesn't display it since I'm under 15 reps. I appreciate your help.